# Area inscribed by four parabolas $y=x^2,y=3x^2,x=y^2$ and $x=2y^2$.

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I want to calculate the area inscribed by the four parabolas $y=x^2,y=3x^2,x=y^2$ and $x=2y^2$. Let us call this area $S$. We want to use the substitution $\Phi(u,v)=(u^2/v,v^2/u)$. By substitution of variables, $$
\int_{S} dA=\int_{\Phi(S)}\frac{1}{\det(Jac_\Phi)}dA
$$
We calculate that $\frac{1}{\det(Jac_\Phi)}(u,v)=\frac{1}{3},$ so we have to find $\Phi(S)$. How can we find $\Phi(S)$, a priori, it doesn't seem to be a simple geometric object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a simple object: a rectangle. Observe that its boundary is made up by four pieces of level sets of the functions $F_1(x,y)=x^2/y$ and $F_2(x,y)=y^2/x$, namely $F_1=1/3$, $F_1=1$, $F_2=1$ and $F_2=1/2$.

Comment: I did not understand at first. Yes, I did. I corrected it.